# How to do cache management with automatic versioning on static files in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, caching, auto-versioning

Cache is not refreshed after deployment of an asp.net project. According to my research there are few ways to do this. But i am interested in a way that is automatic versioning on static files like js, css etc. I googled for this goal and i found some useful things;

1. Omar Al Zabir's implementation - [Click](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/203288/Automatic-JS-CSS-versioning-to-update-browser-cach?msg=3918527#xx3918527xx)
2. CombineAndMinify Nuget Package - [Click](http://aspnetperformance.com/post/Package-that-speeds-up-loading-of-JavaScript-CSS-and-image-files.aspx)

I tried both of them and i got some errors. I don't want to spend time to find where the error occurred. If you want to find the error where it is, [click](https://code.google.com/archive/p/autojscssversion/issues/3) for the issue.

So, i would like to ask, is there any way to do automatic versioning in asp.net?

PS. I am talking about AUTOMATIC versioning not manuel like changing each file name.